# scp to /home changes permissions?

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, scp, selinux, home

This would be illustrated very nicely with an scheme. When I write "Test: OK" or "Test: FAIL" I am restarting apache server (httpd service). Basically, performing everything as root in the target_host:

```
scp user@source_host:/etc/httpd/conf.d/custom.conf /home
mv /home/custom.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

Test: FAIL

```
scp user@source_host:/etc/httpd/conf.d/custom.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

Test: OK

```
scp user@source_host:/etc/httpd/conf.d/custom.conf /
mv /custom.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

Test: OK

The same behaviour when using:

```
scp root@source_host...
```

When Test: FAIL:

```
Iniciando httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 221 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/httpd/conf.d/custom.conf: Permission denied
```

*"Iniciando" is the Spanish word for Starting*

The permissions inside conf.d are always (ls -ln):

```
-r--r--r--. 1 0 0 311 Jun 18 14:19 custom.conf
```

Is scp changing something in these files so that apache can or not read them?

Comment: Why are you copying a file to /home? Why not just scp the file to /root or directly into /etc/httpd/...?

Comment: Everything started when I was unable to read some files I had into /home directory. I had them there due to its huge size (sys admin said it was an error to create such a little / partition in benefit of a /home almost empty one). It seemed easier to place the files I needed in the /home folder rather than resizing partitions at that moment (again, I am not sys admin here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [drupalwatchdog.com](http://drupalwatchdog.com/2/2/apache-selinux)

> SELinux will block Apache processes from reading data labeled as
>   user's home content (user_home_t) or database data (mysql_db_t).

I have learned too that the difference resides in the label's assigned to the files by SELinux. You can check them by `ls -Z`. In my case:

```
-r--r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 custom.conf
-r--r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 custom_ok.conf
```

With the second file Apache restarts. With the first one fails.
In fact, when I move the custon_ok.conf to home, nothing changes. But when I do cp or cp -p to home, the new file has the labels

```
unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0
```

so that Apache will not be able to read it when moved back to /etc/httpd/conf.d

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `scp` changes the permissions. It is creating a new file when it copies and this new file will be created with the default permissions of the directory in which you create it:

```
terdon@local$ ls -l aa
-rwx------ 1 root root 0 Jun 19 15:37 aa
terdon@local$ scp aa terdon@remote:/home/terdon/aa

terdon@remote$ ls -l aa
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 587 2013-06-19 15:38 aa
```

If you do not want this, use the `-p` flag:

> ```
> -p      Preserves modification times, access times, and
>          modes from the original file.
> ```

```
terdon@local$ scp -p aa terdon@remote:/home/terdon/aa
terdon@remote$ ls -l aa
-rwx------ 1 terdon terdon 587 2013-06-19 15:38 aa
```

Another possible problem is that the file's user is changed. If you want to copy configuration files that likely need to be owned by `root` make sure you use `scp root@remote`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be my case, since doing the two first scp above yields files with `-r--r--r--.  1 root          root        2712 Jun 19 16:59 custom.conf`. In fact, with `scp -p` the permissions remain the same (I have done this with explicit different name custom2.conf, so that I have been able to check both permissions at a glance).

Comment: @cantalapiedra that seems weird. What OS are you using? This is how `scp` should work and as you can see I tested it by copying from my local Debian to a remote SUSE host and the permissions are preserved by `-p`.

Comment: Source host is Scientific Linux release 6.3 (Carbon), while target host is Scientific Linux release 6.0 (Carbon). I think that both are running SELinux. However, as I say above, I have the same permissions in both folders and with both methods. At least the ones I know about...